# Smarty include template in both php and javascript (using Smarty and JSmart)

Tags: templates, include, smarty

I am trying to use a single smarty template in both PHP and JavaScript. This works great but I'm trying to figure out how I can use an {include file=""} tag in the template when the JavaScript side expects an element ID and the PHP side expects a file path?

Do the  element IDs have to match the path I will use when on the PHP side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I worked out how to do this, I overwrote the js prototype method for jsmart that requests a template by id:

```
jSmart.prototype.getTemplate = function () {}; // Add your method here
```

That way I can control what to do with the id including mapping it to a template element with a different ID from the passed path.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question looks old, but would like to answer your question since I came across this question via Google and may happen with many others.

xyz.tpl - Template to be included.

```
Hello {$name}
```

pqr.tpl - parent template.

```
There you see the message 
{include file='./xyz.tpl'}
```

Now in Javascript section of a web page define

```
jSmart.prototype.getTemplate = function (name) {
// Load template content here of template 'name' via ajax or DOM. Say here in the e.g. it would be './xyz.tpl'.
};
```

Now just call the parent template

```
<script>
    var tplData = <content of pqr.tpl>; // You can load data in this via ajax or from DOM.
    var tplObj = new jSmart(tplData);
    var output = tplObj.fetch({'name': 'World'});
    alert(output);
</script>
```

Source:-
https://github.com/umakantp/jsmart/wiki/Include-Templates